# Should Observer be in constructor

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an application that needs to send minor rxjs requests to reload certain methods in other components (components that are very much higher up in the navigation tree so inputs and outputs would be too messy). I have a child component which sends a boolean value to a service:

**Child Component:**

```
myMethod(){
 this.reloadComponentService.changeReload(true)
};
```

**Reload Service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ReloadComponentService {

    private _reloadSource = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    reload$ = this._reloadSource.asObservable();

    constructor() { }

    changeReload(val) {
        this._reloadSource.next(val);
        this._reloadSource.next(false); //reset it
    }
}
```

And my very high level **parent component** which is listening for changes to this has the following code in it's constructor:

```
constructor(private _reloadComponentService: ReloadComponentService) {

        this.subscription1 = this._reloadComponentService.reload$
            .subscribe(
            response => {

                if ((response === true)) {
                    this.getUnreadMessageCount();
                }
            });
    }
```

My question is should the observer be in the constructor in the first place? I know it works but I've heard generally people don't like putting any code in the constructor because of runtime issues.

Comment: If you take care of your subscription properly (unsubscribe it), there is no issue with this. Alternatively you can put your subscription in ngOnInit

Comment: Subscribing in the constructor would mean `this.getUnreadMessageCount();` could get called when the component is being created, this is quite unpredictable. I would also suggest subscribing later on. It is perfectly ok to declare observables in constructors though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the rest of your code, but instead of subscribing, why don't you just use the [`async`](https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular#async-pipe) pipe in your template:

```html
<span>Unread: {{ unreadMessageCount$ | async }}</span>
```

```js
readonly unreadMessageCount$: Observable<number> = this.rcs.reload$.pipe(
  // only continue if response is truthy
  filter((response) => response),
  // connect to observable returned from getUnreadMessageCount
  switchMap(() => this.getUnreadMessageCount())
);

constructor(private rcs: ReloadComponentService) {}
```

This way you have no code inside your constructor (neater, there is no real difference in doing it in the `ngOnInit`), and you don't have to deal with subscribing and unsubscribing as this is handled inside the `async` pipe.

The [`filter`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter) operator only emits values that pass the provided condition. Where as the [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) will map to another observable.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Please could you describe briefly what pipe, filter and switchMap are doing?

Comment: @AndrewJuniorHoward These are quite basic terms when working with angular and/or Observables. For the async pipe you can check [here](https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular#async-pipe). For the other things I'll update the answer with links

Answer (score 2):

You can place the subscription in `ngOnInit`. You should also not forget to unsubscribe; for example in `ngOnDestroy`.